# SQL Server 2012 How to determine if all the values in table A are in table B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables (A & B) that share a common value (Color), both tables can have any number of rows. I am trying to find a way to determine if all the distinct 'Colors' in table A exist in table B:

I have tried using EXCEPT, which almost works, unfortunately it returns false when table B has more Colors than table A, which is irrelevant all i care about is if every distinct Color from table A is in table B. I have been fiddling with both EXISTS and IN but can't see to get the correct results

```sql
declare @TableA table (Color varchar(10))
declare @TableB table (Color varchar(10))

insert into @TableA(Color) values ('red')
insert into @TableA(Color) values ('blue')
insert into @TableA(Color) values ('green')
--insert into @TableA(Color) values ('orange')


insert into @TableB(Color) values ('red')
insert into @TableB(Color) values ('blue')
insert into @TableB(Color) values ('green')
insert into @TableB(Color) values ('yellow')
insert into @TableB(Color) values ('purple')

IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT Color FROM @TableA
    EXCEPT
    SELECT Color FROM @TableB
)
SELECT 'true'
ELSE SELECT 'false'
```

I would like the above code to yield 'true'.

```
IF table A Colors > table B Colors THEN false
IF table A Colors <= table B Colors THEN true.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this. You could use a left join for this pretty easily.

```
if exists
(
    SELECT a.Color 
    FROM @TableA a
    left join @TableB b on b.Color = a.Color
    where b.Color is null
) 
    select 'Some Colors in A are not in B'
else
    select 'ALL Colors in A exist in B'
```

Comment: I' mot sure why i did not think of left join, I was clearly over thinking the issue, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could also just use your existing query and add DISTINCT:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Color FROM @TableA
    EXCEPT
    SELECT DISTINCT Color FROM @TableB
)
SELECT 'true'
ELSE SELECT 'false'
```

Comment: Even with DISTINCT this doesn't yield the desired results. thanks though